# Language parameter on the link

Tags: java, spring-mvc

exists an easy method to have the language always at first in the link without change every controller in Spring MVC?

For example

- site.com/en/link.html
- site.com/de/link.html
- site.com/it/link.html

and this language parameter pass automatically "language=en".

I'm using LocaleChangeInterceptor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocaleChangeInterceptor looks for locale *changes*. It doesn't resolve a locale for the request. What you need is an implementation of LocaleResolver interface, specifically

```
resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request)
```

method, which would get that language parameter from the URL.